# How to edit/rename mailmerge fields(tags) in docx file without having database that created this mailmerge fields? python docx-mailmerge==0.4.0

Tags: docx, libreoffice, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

In my python django project I work with docx MailMerge package (docx-mailmerge==0.4.0)
And I have specific tags in a docx files, but I did not create this docx files and those mailmerge tags, right now I have some tag that I want to edit, but I do not know how do I do that, I need this tag to be exact type like others but I do not know how to view data types of other tags.
[image: here is how this tags look, apparently otp_pass tag is still pointing to fio_full tag in mailmerge]

sorry for my bad explanation, I do not know anything about docx and mailmerge :(

I tried editing tags in libreoffice but I cant edit them, I need some 'database' to paste this tags from there, but I do not have it, I only have some docx files with tags, but I cant find this tag anywhere in this docx files so I need to recreate it, but I dunno how...

Comment: Actually I just found the solution - https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html